# How to write a fixed length file from Big query to GCS bucket

Tags: google-bigquery

my input table is like this

[image: my input table is like this]

and these are the fixed lengths for each column

[image]

how can i write a fixed lenth file into GCS bucket  from bigquery  like this using bigquery

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you open to another approach which can you fixed-delimited output is in the inline `select` query from the `table` with `format` and `rpad` functions.

Input data:

[image]

```
  EXPORT DATA
  OPTIONS (
    uri = 'gs://sandbox-bucket/*.csv',
    format = 'CSV',
    overwrite = true,
    field_delimiter='|'
    )
AS (
SELECT 
FORMAT('%s', RPAD(cast(id as string), 6)) as id,
FORMAT('%s', RPAD(cast(firstname as string), 20)) as firstname,
FORMAT('%s', RPAD(cast(lastname as string), 20)) as lastname,
FORMAT('%t', RPAD(cast(dob as string), 10)) as dob
FROM YOUR_DATESET.TABLE  
ORDER BY DOB
)
```

Output:

[image]